# How can I make an exclusive graphical interface only activate when a user has a gamepass in Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

I am starting to program in roblox, and I am making a Menu only for users who have a gamepass, I would like to know how I can make an exclusive graphical interface appear when a user has a gamepass, and the error here is that when a user buy that gamepass automatically the exclusive interface is activated to all the users of the server, I would like to know how to fix this problem.

The Script is on ServerScriptService

```
local MarketPlaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")

local GamePass = 100725261
local Tool = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.TPMenu

function compra(jugador)

    local loTiene = false
    
    local success, errorMensaje = pcall(function()
        loTiene = MarketPlaceService:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(jugador.UserId, GamePass)
    end)
    
    if loTiene then
        game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.TPMenu.Visible = true
    end
    
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    compra(player)
end)
```

I tried to made this in a LocalScript and is not working

Answer (score 0):

StarterGui is put into each Player's PlayerGui after they spawn, so editing it for one user would mean that other users would also see the changes after respawning. A better option would be to modify PlayerGui instead, like this:

```lua
function compra(jugador)

    local loTiene = false
    
    local success, errorMensaje = pcall(function()
        loTiene = MarketPlaceService:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(jugador.UserId, GamePass)
    end)
    
    if loTiene then
        jugador.CharacterAdded:Connect(function() -- Ran every time the player spawns
            workspace:WaitForChild(jugador.Name) -- Wait for player to finish spawning
            jugador.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.TPMenu.Visible = true
        end)
    end
end
```

Keep it as a Script in ServerScriptService.